# How to insert text on the end of sql statement result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

For example, my sql command returns this

```
 01234567
```

So how would I be able to insert text so it would return this at the end of the statement. So if I return multiple values, then TEXT would only appear at the end.

```
 01234567TEXT
```

I cant seem to find too much online for assistance but I know this is possible. My current sql command is as follows:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT PID = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8) + CAST(PID AS VARCHAR(8)),8) FROM dbo.MDRMASTER WHERE PARENTPID = @PARENTPID",con);
```

Any help or a point to the right direction would be awesome. Thank you so much

**UPDATE** I misworded the question in the beginning. I ment to say at the end of the last statement. Thanks Siva for clearing that up. I did thumbs up everyone though. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Based on your edit you'd need code to loop through the values returned from  the `SqlCommand` then append the 'TEXT' value in your c# code. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: the last row yes. I hoped to have ment that by saying "at the end" Im pretty new and not too tech savy yet. Add your answer back Siva :P

Comment: its 2008 r2, but your answer was right :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need the text at the end of the result. Then you need to perform a **`UNION`**.

*Code*:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("
SELECT PID = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8) + 
CAST(PID AS VARCHAR(8)),8) 
FROM dbo.MDRMASTER 
WHERE PARENTPID = @PARENTPID 
UNION SELECT 'TEXT'",
con);
```

Answer (score 4):

You would just need to concatenate your string on the end of your result:

Add:

```
+ 'TEXT'
```

And the sql command would be

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT PID = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8) + CAST(PID AS VARCHAR(8)),8) + 'TEXT' FROM dbo.MDRMASTER WHERE PARENTPID = @PARENTPID",con);
```

Based on your Edit I think you only want the TEXT appended to the final record. If so, then you could do the following:

```
create table temp
(
    field varchar(10)
)

insert into temp values ('12345678')
insert into temp values ('23456789')
insert into temp values ('34567890')
insert into temp values ('45678901')
insert into temp values ('56789012')

select field
from temp
WHERE field != (SELECT Max(field) from temp)
UNION
select field + 'TEXT'
from temp
WHERE field = (SELECT Max(field) from temp)

drop table temp
```

If you just need the TEXT as the last row then you would do:

```
create table temp
(
    field varchar(10)
)

insert into temp values ('12345678')
insert into temp values ('23456789')
insert into temp values ('34567890')
insert into temp values ('45678901')
insert into temp values ('56789012')

select field
from temp
UNION
select 'TEXT'

drop table temp
```

Your SQLCommand would be

```
SqlCommand command 
    = new SqlCommand("SELECT PID = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8) + CAST(PID AS VARCHAR(8)),8) 
                      FROM dbo.MDRMASTER 
                      WHERE PARENTPID = @PARENTPID 
                      UNION 
                      SELECT 'TEXT'",con);
```

Answer (score 4):

If database value is a string, concatenation is as simple as this...

```
SELECT T.col + 'TEXT'
FROM Table AS T
```

If database value is not a string, you might need to cast before concatenating, like this...

```
SELECT CAST(T.col AS nvarchar)  + 'TEXT'
FROM Table AS T
```

From your code, it would be more like this...

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8) + CAST(PID AS VARCHAR(8)),8) + 'TEXT' AS PID FROM dbo.MDRMASTER WHERE PARENTPID = @PARENTPID", con);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just append the text in your SQL -

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT PID = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8) + CAST(PID AS VARCHAR(8)),8) + 'TEXT' FROM dbo.MDRMASTER WHERE PARENTPID = @PARENTPID",con);
```

Comment: that is true, but if I get multiple values then 'TEXT' will be at the end of every value. I should rephrase my question

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use the "`+`" operator in your SQL `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT PID = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8) + CAST(PID AS VARCHAR(8)),8) + 'TEXT'
```

This would end up making your code look like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT PID = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8) + CAST(PID AS VARCHAR(8)),8) 
                                      FROM dbo.MDRMASTER 
                                      WHERE PARENTPID = @PARENTPID"
    ,con);
```

See the MSDN article on [String concatenation in Transact SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to input a text, for example "text"
then just do this:

select 'text'

You can then add it above or below the result of your actual query with UNION

Comment: Please add in sample code to clarify your answer with reference to the actual question